# Make Java sort symbols after alphabet (like Linux sort does)

Tags: java, string, sorting

When I do a sort in Linux:

```
echo -en "[a\na" > test && sort test > test2
```

I get

```
a
[a
```

But in Java `[a` comes before `a`. Is it possible to make it work like Linux does?

Answer (score 1):

So, first thing, the sort order of the `sort` command depends on the locale (especially `LC_COLLATE`). With `LC_ALL` set to `C`, the sort order will be the same as Java:

```
$ echo -ne "[a\na" | LC_ALL=C sort
[a
a
$
```

So, if you just use the normal Java sort and put the letters and digits first, you can use something like that:

```
final List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("[a");
lst.add("a");

Collections.sort(lst, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String s1, final String s2) {
        if (s1==s2)
            return 0;
        if (s1==null)
            return 1;
        if (s2==null)
            return -1;
        for (int i=0; i<s1.length()&&i<s2.length(); i++)
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(s1.charAt(i)) | Character.isLetterOrDigit(s2.charAt(i))) {
                return Character.isLetterOrDigit(s1.charAt(i))?-1:1;
            } else if (s1.charAt(i)!=s2.charAt(i))
                break;
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});

for (final String str: lst)
    System.out.println(str);
```

But if you want something more complex, based on `LC_COLLATE`, you will have to use a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) and maybe [define your own](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html) [`RuleBasedCollator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).